# SQL Producing foreign key constraint fails error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Why is my SQL producing the foreign key constraint fails error?
I tried my SELECT and it works in a separate query. The INSERT is what is failing and I dont know why?

Here is my DB structure:
[image]

My query is:

```
"INSERT INTO grades(student_id,grade,gradebook_id) 
VALUES(".$students.",".$grader.",
(SELECT gradebook_id FROM gradebooks 
     WHERE teacher_id=".$_SESSION['userId']." AND gradebook_title='Language Arts'))"
```

Comment: The student_id you're trying to insert probably doesn't exist, or the fact that you're not passing in an assignment_id

Comment: Thanks! I did a vardump and my students variable was NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Evan M in the comment above, the assignment_id was not being passed in and therefore it was NULL.

The issue has been resolved.